# Keep buddypress admin bar stationary at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, buddypress

I  just installed buddypress on my wordpress powered website and I would like to prevent the admin bar from following the screen as you scroll down. How can I make it stay stationary at the top of the page and allow it to go out of view as you scroll down?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about how they implement it... Items staying put in the window can be handled through css with a `position: fixed; top: 0` type syntax. Changing the position to `absolute` is probably the most straightforward change; it will change to just being stuck along the top when scrolled to the top instead of stuck along the top always. Or there are a number of ways to do it through javascript. Do you know how it's working? Try inspecting the element in a browser (firebug in firefox or chrome) and checking what css rules are applied to the header. Or post a url, at least.

Comment: That did it! I changed position from fixed to absolute and wallah! it works. Thank you very much for your help:)